# is there a timeout for Ethernet.begin?

Tags: arduino-uno, ethernet

I'm working on a project, but just for testing, I haven't connected it to the internet yet, even though the code SHOULD be ready to roll out.

When trying to test some of my code with the serial console, I realized my program was locking up and I traced it down to here. Now my arduino uno and ethernet shield isn't currently connected to the internet, so my question is, how could I timeout this function so that I can keep my program running when there's no internet to connect it too.

Here's my code in the setup function

```
if (Ethernet.begin(mac) == 0) {
    Serial.println("Failed to configure Ethernet using DHCP");
    // try to congifure using IP address instead of DHCP:
    Ethernet.begin(mac, ip);
  }
```

If anyone has any thoughts or suggestions, I'd definitely appreciate it.

Answer (score 3):

The default timeout is 1 minute for DHCP. There is also a response timeout, and in the library millis is used for timeouts. I don't know if there is a timeout for everything, but I suppose there is.

If it stops working when no ethernet cable is connected, that would be a bug. If something like that is in the library, then you have no way to bypass the Ethernet.begin when it took too long. How long did you wait ?

This is the source code for Ethernet.begin: [Ethernet.cpp](https://github.com/arduino-libraries/Ethernet/blob/master/src/Ethernet.cpp)

Comment: Thanks, this is good to know. I don't know for certain how long I gave it, I'm guessing the customary 30 seconds so I'll need to give this another run and double my patience, lol

Comment: The code can actually hang up in `W5100Class::execCmdSn` function. It waits for command to complete by reading a register and waiting for read to return 0. If it returns non-zero for some reason (poor contact, etc.), the function will hang up.